# How can I dynamically update a formula reference based on the current date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook that tracks billings and expenses for every month and compares them to forecasts.

Every month, to generate reports, we need to update the formula references so it points to the current month.

Is there a way to dynamically automate the formula references based on the current date?

For example:
A2 | Current Date: `=Today()`
A3 | Current Month: `=TEXT(AT,"mmm")`

Then have return formulas update based on the current month? Would a long elaborate switch function be able to do this or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Sounds like you may benefit from [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function. You can find several examples here in SO

Comment: Why don't you share some of those formulas that need to get updated?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but if you are always going to want the current month, you can try the below formula. Its very similar to your current date formula.

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")
```